# flash as3 rounding numbers automatically

Tags: actionscript-3, numbers, rounding

I wrote out a long post trying to explain the exact details of the problem im having, but instead i think ill keep it simple, and ask an example question here:

```
var n1:Number = 9.99999999999999;
n1 += 0.000000000000009;
var n2:Number = n1 + 10;
var n3:Number = n1 - 10;
```

Long story short, n1 = 9.99....7, n2 = 20, n3 = 10.

If i try to make a comparison between n1 and n3, they should be the same but they arn't.  I dont care if flash rounds it or not, i just need them to be the same (and they arn't, cause flash rounds in one case, and not the other).

Is there some standard solution for a problem like this?

P.S. I dont need this precision on my numbers, but i also would not like to micromanage the rounding of the numbers EVERY time i do a manipulation (that seems like it could add a LOT of code to the mix).  If this is the only solution however, i guess ill just have to do a lot of rounding throughout the code, ha.

Comment: You mean `n3 = n2 - 10` not `n3 = n1 - 10`, right?

Comment: The trick to having "rounded numbers" is to avoid IEEE 754 floating point numbers completely, and stick with integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Number` in flash is a double precision floating point number. Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) about them. These "problems" are not unique to flash, but just have to do with how these numbers are stored.

There are a couple of options. Here is a [quick little library](http://joshblog.net/2007/01/30/flash-floating-point-number-errors/) for fuzzy comparing numbers, within a certain margin of error. Another option would be implement a [fixed point math library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).

Comment: ALthough this does answer my question, it doesn't give me the "simple" solution i was hoping for.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a problem to just wrap in int() if you're trying to compare?

```
trace(int(n1) == int(n3));
```